# How to set the click listener on a button generated by my adapter?

Tags: android, user-interface, adapter

This is my simple adapter:

```
public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mText = {
            R.string.main_team,
            R.string.main_league,
            R.string.main_economy,
            R.string.main_arena,
            R.string.main_staff,
            R.string.main_team_up
    };

    public MainAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mText.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button buttonView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            buttonView = new Button(mContext);
            buttonView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 45));
            //imageView.setScaleType(Button.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            buttonView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        } else {
            buttonView = (Button) convertView;
        }

        buttonView.setText(mText[position]);
        return buttonView;
    }

}
```

Every button has to start its own intent.
I was thinking of using a switch case based on the position but it seems really "stupid" as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new object, eg. `ActivityLaunchButtonData` to store the button Text and the button Intent.

Then I would have an array of ActivityLaunchButtonData objects.

Then in the `getView` method I'd have something like:

```
ActivityLaunchButtonData activityLaunchButtonData = activityLaunchButtonDataArray[position];
buttonView.setText(activityLaunchButtonData.getText());
buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = activityLaunchButtonData.getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Used an array but I chose an array of OnClickListener, then I used the View arg0 to launch the activity.

Comment: Only negative about a separate array for the onClick actions like that is you'll have to maintain two array's and keep them in sync. Like if you move two things around in mText array you'll have to move the relevant onClickListener's around too.

Comment: True, I have to say it's the main menu so there's no really a real reason to move them around, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, in your adapter the intent to fire and the data to put in it you can try something like that:

```
public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private Integer[] mText = {
        R.string.main_team,
        R.string.main_league,
        R.string.main_economy,
        R.string.main_arena,
        R.string.main_staff,
        R.string.main_team_up
    };

    public MainAdapter(Context c,Activity a) {
        mContext = c;
        mActivity = a;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button buttonView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            buttonView = new Button(mContext);
            buttonView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 45));
            //imageView.setScaleType(Button.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            buttonView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        } else {
            buttonView = (Button) convertView;
        }

        buttonView.setText(mText[position]);
        // For exemple a String, but setTag takes an object
        buttonView.setTag("dataToSendThrewTheIntent");
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return buttonView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String dataToSendThrewTheIntent = (String) v.getTag();
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, DestinationActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("key", dataToSendThrewTheIntent);
        mActivity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This method avoids multiple onClick listeners.