# Call/modify current activity on click of a button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity "`MyListActivity`". I have an adapter associated with it "`MyGridAdapter`". It contains a grid of buttons (say 3). Each button has a "`OnClickListner`()". 
On click of the 1st button, I would have to take the same action. So, instead of creating similar another activity, I decide to RE-USE the same page. Meaning: I need to call "`MyListActivity`" but with some modified parameters- increased number of buttons etc...
I tried to use, "`invalidate()`" on button click. But it re-loads the same page without any changes.

How to call the same activity from a function in the adapter?

My work around for the problem: I created another "`tempActivity`". in one of the function I am trying to start the previous activity.
code inside "`MyGridAdapter`":

```
TempActivity temp=new TempActivity();
temp.setIntentObj(<parameters>);
```

inside "TempActivity":

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,ListActivity.class);        //this gives a "NullPointerException"
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the adapter class, we can start an activity using `context.startActivity(intent)` I did not know that we can access "start Activity" from adapter... but now it's working just fine!! Thanks a lot for your recommendation...

Comment: you can, you just have to be using the correct `context` which, in this case, would be your "Activity"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly; you should update the List that is passed to the Adapter and then invoke adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). (method name might be a bit different, I'm typing on my mobile and can't look it up).

The List you update must be the same List that the adapter was given so you'll have to keep a reference of it as a property of your class.

Comment: I think my question is not quite clear.
I want to display a different list but using the same view. 
I have to do this at run-time. I cannot say which list will be called next. If the same type of list is called next, then, instead of making a new view/activity, I would rather like to use the same activity/view.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you just want to update your current List with different data, right? Do it the way I describe above.

Comment: But i need to change the list ONCLICK of a button, this code is in the Adapter. So how to implement that?

Comment: In your adapter's `getView` method you would just create the button with the new onClickListener, see this post of mine for a similar solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422136/how-to-set-the-click-listener-on-a-button-generated-by-my-adapter/7422531#7422531

Comment: :D thanks for the link. I didn't want to use arrays, but the person who had commented below solved my problem... Thanks a lot...

Comment: `context.startActivity(intent)` is the code that worked!!! and I am able to start respective activities on button click!!!